# Função "Procv" + "Corresp" da erro ao inserir uma caixa de combinação (ActiveX) com referências numéricas

Tags: microsoft-excel

Fiz uma função "procv" + "corresp" para procurar valores de uma tabela e adicionei uma caixa de combinação(activex), e adicionei números para o "corresp" buscar em colunas o valor procurado, porém ao usar a caixa de combinação o valor procurado da '#N/D' o que está acontecendo?? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boas @Elienay, qual a finalidade que pretendes com o `CORRESP`? É indicar o nº da coluna do qual pretendes obter o resultado?

Comment: Sim! é isso mesmo. Mas quando eu uso a caixa de combinação(activex), ele joga um número, mas em formato de texto e a função "Procv" + "Corresp" não reconhece e acaba dando erro, somente da certo quando eu coloco um texto normal na sequencia destacada em verde da função "corresp"

Comment: Caso eu selecione "Região" ele não da erro, mas caso eu jogue um número ele da erro, isso quando eu uso a caixa de combinação(activex). Eu queria jogar um número ao invés de digitar uma palavra normal nos valores superiores referente ao "corresp". Eu pretendo usar o activex porque nele da para alterar o tamanho da fonte e outras características

Comment: Para ver se entendi correctamente o que pretendes, caso procures **SUL** e selecciones o **1** o resultado que esperas é **100**, caso procures **NORDESTE** e selecciones **3** o resultado é **3000**. É isto que pretendes?

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo

Comment: desculpa mas não consigo ajudar neste tema. Não entendo porque o ActiveX coloca o nº em texto.. Se for mesmo necessário utilizares o ActiveX podemos criar uma macro em que cada vez que alteres o número ela selecciona a célula e converte de texto para número.. Ou podes esperar por alguém que saiba como solucionar isto sem macro.